# Explain Like I'm Five version for Variograms in R's gstat package

Tags: r, geostatistics, variogram, kriging

Long story short, I asked a question on StackOverflow about Variograms in the gstat package in R. The person who answered gave me some tips on creating the variogram using the package.

My dataset is horrible, only having 4 points. And yet he (or she) found a way for me to create the variogram when I could not on my own. And that was by changing the parameters: `width` and `cutoff`.

I accepted the answer as it answered my question, but I can't help but ask: What do these individual parameters mean?

I'm not a geostatistician, I'm an IT guy. Can anybody please explain to me the simplest, high-level definition of the parameters? And if its not too much to ask, can you also point me to some materials that also give an "explain like i'm five" approach to the whole kriging process?

For full details of the question I asked on StackOverflow, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434057/create-variogram-in-rs-gstat-package/43434889?noredirect=1#comment73927712_43434889.

Thank you to anyone who responds.

This is my first time on Cross Validated too, so... please be gentle.

Comment: Good question: but one thing to be aware of is that one does not perform geostatistics lightly.  If you want any of its advertised benefits--"best, unbiased," *etc*--then you can't use it as a black box. Four points for estimating a variogram is ridiculously low (there are only six point pairs available); you won't be able to rely on the results.  Rules of thumb vary from 20 to 100 points *minimum* for variography; in some special cases--often for illustrative purposes--people have used smaller datasets.  The smallest I ever encountered was seven (giving 21 point pairs).

Comment: I really have no other option though, Sensors/stations from where I am are pretty few and far apart. But that's kinda the point, I want to show that this can work provided some more data. I'm just presenting a methodology for future researchers. Methodolody being, krig daily, take results, feed to ANN.

Comment: You didn't answer my question though.